# Collision not being detected Unity2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collision

I am trying to make an object that upon collision with another object, gets destroyed. I have also used Debug.Log and it turns out that the collision is not even detected. Here is the code

```
     public class Enemy_1 : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
     {
         if (col.gameObject.tag.Equals ("AttackArea"))
         {
             Destroy(gameObject);

         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Do your objects have `Rigidbody2D` components and `Collider2D`?

Comment: Also, check your collision detection type.  You could try changing it to `Continuous`.  Also, the Havok Physics is supposed to be faster.  That might be fun to try.

Comment: instead of string comparing rather use `col.gameObject.CompareTag("AttackArea")` to avoid silent fails for typos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the community!

To allow us better to understand the context, next time provide some inspector screenshots of these objects. It will be easier for both of us!

Now, for your problem, there might be one (or combination) of few reasons:

1. None of the two objects have `Rigidbody2D` attached. For collision to be detected, at least one of two must be a `Rigidbody2D`. ...
2. Other object is not tagged as `AttackArea`. Thus, tag equation returns false. ...
3. Other object's collider is marked as `is trigger`. In this case `OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D)` is called instead of `OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D)`.

Check for each of these and let us know!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25757777)

Comment: Thanks for clarification! Though, I thought giving reasonable options to check could be counted as answer.

Comment: Hey Thanks for your reply!!!. I'm new to all of this and i thought that a tag was the name of the object but then i realized what a tag was and now it finally works.Thanks for helping me i spent a lot of time trying to figure it out...